# Image upload: Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, image-upload

I am having issues in image upload. There are two image upload section, in first upload it works fine. but when I am uploading in second upload image only changes in first section. Below are the code details:

```
<div class="upload">
  <div class="center_image">
    <div class="image-upload">
      <label for="file-input">
        <img *ngIf="!url1==true" src="/assets/images/upload.png">
        <img [src]="url1" height="60">
      </label>

      <input id="file-input" type="file" (change)="readUrl($event)" />
    </div>
    <h6 *ngIf="!url1==true" class="font_u">Upload Front</h6>
    <br>
    <div class="li_ol">
      <p>The following details must be clearly visible :</p>
      <ol>
        <li>Name</li>
        <li>Date of Birth
        </li>
        <li>Gender</li>
        <li> Aadhaar number
        </li>
        <li>Photograph</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="upload">
  <div class="center_image">
    <div class="image-upload">
      <label for="file-input">
        <img *ngIf="!url2==true" src="/assets/images/upload.png">
        <img [src]="url2" height="60">
      </label>

      <input id="file-input" type="file" (change)="onSelectFileBack($event)" />
    </div>
    <h6 *ngIf="!url2==true" class="font_u">Upload Back</h6>
    <br>
    <div class="li_ol">
      <p>The following details must be clearly visible :</p>
      <ol>
        <li>Address</li>
        <li> Aadhaar number</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
readUrl(event: any) {
  alert(event);
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (event: any) => {
      this.url1 = event.target.result;
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
  }
}

onSelectFileBack(event: any) {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (event: any) => {
      this.url2 = event.target.result;
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
  }
}
```

In both the uploads image only uploads on first section but both the div's and even functions are different.

Comment: it's working file on my system

Answer (score 0):

The file input in the first section:

```
   <input id="file-input" type="file" (change)="readUrl($event)" />
```

has the same `id` as the file input in the second section:

```
   <input id="file-input" type="file" (change)="onSelectFileBack($event)" />
```

Change one of them so that they are each unique.

Comment: If I am changing any one one of the then that input section is not working!

Answer (score 0):

Tried creating stackblitz with same code as above and it is working as expected. only respective input filed change events are getting trigged.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hmuzzd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I don't know what is happening with code it is always calling readurl function.

Comment: can you create stackblitz. will validate

Comment: In stackblitz code is working perfectly by in my system it creates issue. One more thing if i removed id from input id="file-input" or even change something is id then event file system is not working

Answer (score 0):

add click event to label.

```
<label for="file-input" (click)="onChoose()">
```

remove id="file-input" from input tag and add "#fileinput" template variable.

```
<input #fileinput type="file" (change)="onSelectFileBack($event)" />
```

create onChoose method in component.ts file.

```
@ViewChild('fileinput') fileInput : ElementRef; 
onChoose():void{
  this.fileInput.nativeElement.click();
}
```